Couchbase Bootstrap Exception: UnsupportedAddressFamilyException with CCCP
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to connect to Couchbase using the .NET client. Here are the specifics of the problem:Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
i am trying to create bucket but it throwing an error as shown in the image:


It says check the inner exceptions for details.  So what are these innerexception details?  Also, please post the code itself as text.  It is difficult to copy paste from an image!

off-topic: fortunately CCCP doesn't exist since '91

UnsupportedAddressFamily sounds like a IP6 address is being specified where only IP4 is supported - or the other way around.

This looks like .NET SDK 2.X code for Couchbase Server (i.e. 2.7 from here). You would need to use the Mobile .NET SDK for Couchbase Mobile.

That code looks like .NET SDK for Couchbase Server and not Couchbase Lite. If that's the case, it shouldn't be tagged as couchbase-lite.
It also seems that is a very old version of the .NET SDK which is no longer supported and could, in fact, NOT support ipv6, but I have no means to verify that.
Please refer to 3.3-3.6 current, supported, versions.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
